# Clipping netCDF file to a shapefile and cloning the metadata variables in R

Tags: copy, netcdf, clipping, netcdf4, terra

I have NetCDF files (e.g https://data.ceda.ac.uk/neodc/esacci/lakes/data/lake_products/L3S/v1.0/2019 global domain), and I want to extract the data based on a  shapefile boundary ( in this case a Lake here - https://www.sciencebase.gov/catalog/item/530f8a0ee4b0e7e46bd300dd) and then save clipped data as a NetCDF file but retain all the original metadata and variables names within the clipped file. This is what I have done far

```
library(rgdal)
library(sf)
library(ncdf4)
library(terra)

#Read in the shapefile of Lake 
Lake_shape <- readOGR("C:/Users/CEDA/hydro_p_LakeA/hydro_p_A.shp")
# Reading the netcdf file using Terra Package function rast
test <- rast("ESACCI-LAKES-L3S-LK_PRODUCTS-MERGED-20190705-fv1.0.nc")
# List of some of variables names for orginal dataset 
      head(names(test))
[1] "water_surface_height_above_reference_datum" "water_surface_height_uncertainty"           "lake_surface_water_extent"                 
[4] "lake_surface_water_extent_uncertainty"      "lake_surface_water_temperature"             "lswt_uncertainty"   
                                 
#Clipping data to smaller Lake domain using the crop function in Terra Package
test3 <- crop(test, Lake_shape)
#Listing the some variables names for clipped data
head(names(test3))
[1] "water_surface_height_above_reference_datum" "water_surface_height_uncertainty"           "lake_surface_water_extent"                 
[4] "lake_surface_water_extent_uncertainty"      "lake_surface_water_temperature"             "lswt_uncertainty" 


# Writing the crop dataset as netcdf or Raster Layer using the WriteCDF function 

filepath<-"Lake_A_ESACCI-LAKES-L3S-LK_PRODUCTS-MERGED-20020501-fv1.0"
fname <- paste0( "C:/Users/CEDA/",filepath,".nc")
rnc <- writeCDF(test3, filename =fname, overwrite=T)”
```

My main issue here when I read in clipped the netCDF file I don’t seem to be able to keep the names of the data variables of the original NetCDF.  They are all being renamed automatically when I am saving the clipped dataset as a new netCDF using the writeCDF function.

```
#Reading in the new clipped file
 LakeA<-rast("Lake_A_ESACCI-LAKES-L3S-LK_PRODUCTS-MERGED-20020501-fv1.0.nc")
> head(names(LakeA))
[1] "Lake_A_ESACCI-LAKES-L3S-LK_PRODUCTS-MERGED-20020501-fv1.0_1" "Lake_A_ESACCI-LAKES-L3S-LK_PRODUCTS-MERGED-20020501-fv1.0_2"
[3] "Lake_A_ESACCI-LAKES-L3S-LK_PRODUCTS-MERGED-20020501-fv1.0_3" "Lake_A_ESACCI-LAKES-L3S-LK_PRODUCTS-MERGED-20020501-fv1.0_4"
[5] "Lake_A_ESACCI-LAKES-L3S-LK_PRODUCTS-MERGED-20020501-fv1.0_5" "Lake_A_ESACCI-LAKES-L3S-LK_PRODUCTS-MERGED-20020501-fv1.0_6"
```

So is it possible to clone/copy all the metadata variables from the original NetCDF dataset when clipping to the smaller domain/shapefile in R, then saving as NetCDF? Any guidance on how to do this in R would be really appreciated. (NetCDF and R are all new to me so I am not sure what I am missing or have the in-depth knowledge to sort this).

Comment: try: ```rnc <- writeCDF(test3, filename =fname,varname=names(test3), overwrite=T)``` So that the layer names are assigned by the names in the SpatRaster. It should output the names you are after when reading It back in

Comment: Thank you for your attention and kind response, but when I tried this I got 
Error: [varnames<-,SpatRaster] cannot set these names

Comment: After downloading your data, I too seem to have the same problem. My be best for now to store the names as a 'variable', like: ```rast.names <- names(test3)```, then assign these names to the raster ```names(LakeA) <- rast.names```. Otherwise, seems to me an issue for the author to solve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a NetCDF file with many (52) variables (sub-datasets). When you open the file with `rast` these become "layers". Alternatively you can open the file with `sds` to keep the sub-dataset structure but that does not help you here (and you would need to skip the first two, see below).

```
library(terra)
f <- "ESACCI-LAKES-L3S-LK_PRODUCTS-MERGED-20190101-fv1.0.nc"
r <- rast(f)
r
#class       : SpatRaster 
#dimensions  : 21600, 43200, 52  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#resolution  : 0.008333333, 0.008333333  (x, y)
#extent      : -180, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
#sources     : ESACCI-LAKES-L3S-LK_PRODUCTS-MERGED-20190101-fv1.0.nc:water_surface_height_above_reference_datum  
              ESACCI-LAKES-L3S-LK_PRODUCTS-MERGED-20190101-fv1.0.nc:water_surface_height_uncertainty  
              ESACCI-LAKES-L3S-LK_PRODUCTS-MERGED-20190101-fv1.0.nc:lake_surface_water_extent  
              ... and 49 more source(s)
#varnames    : water_surface_height_above_reference_datum (water surface height above geoid) 
              water_surface_height_uncertainty (water surface height uncertainty) 
              lake_surface_water_extent (Lake Water Extent) 
              ...
#names       : water~datum, water~ainty, lake_~xtent, lake_~ainty, lake_~ature, lswt_~ainty, ... 
#unit        :           m,           m,         km2,         km2,      Kelvin,      Kelvin, ... 
#time        : 2019-01-01
```

Note that there are 52 layers and sources (sub-datasets). There are names

```
head(names(r))
#[1] "water_surface_height_above_reference_datum" "water_surface_height_uncertainty"          
#[3] "lake_surface_water_extent"                  "lake_surface_water_extent_uncertainty"     
#[5] "lake_surface_water_temperature"             "lswt_uncertainty"
```

And also "longnames" (they are often much longer than the variable names, not in this case)

```
head(longnames(r))
# [1] "water surface height above geoid" "water surface height uncertainty" "Lake Water Extent"               
# [4] "Water extent uncertainty"         "lake surface skin temperature"    "Total uncertainty"
```

You can also open the file with `sds`, but you need to skip "lon_bounds" and "lat_bounds" variables (dimensions)

```
s <- sds(f, 3:52)
```

Now read a vector data set (shapefile in this case) and crop

```
lake <- vect("hydro_p_LakeErie.shp")
rc <- crop(r, lake)
rc 

#class       : SpatRaster 
#dimensions  : 182, 555, 52  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#resolution  : 0.008333333, 0.008333333  (x, y)
#extent      : -83.475, -78.85, 41.38333, 42.9  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
#source      : memory 
#names       : water~datum, water~ainty, lake_~xtent, lake_~ainty, lake_~ature, lswt_~ainty, ... 
#min values  :         NaN,         NaN,         NaN,         NaN,     271.170,       0.283, ... 
#max values  :         NaN,         NaN,         NaN,         NaN,     277.090,       0.622, ... 
#time        : 2019-01-01
```

It can be convenient to save this to a `GTiff` file like this (or even better to use the filename argument in crop)

```
gtf <- writeRaster(rc, "test.tif", overwrite=TRUE)
gtf
#class       : SpatRaster 
#dimensions  : 182, 555, 52  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#resolution  : 0.008333333, 0.008333333  (x, y)
#extent      : -83.475, -78.85, 41.38333, 42.9  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
#source      : test.tif 
#names       : water~datum, water~ainty, lake_~xtent, lake_~ainty, lake_~ature, lswt_~ainty, ... 
#min values  :         NaN,         NaN,         NaN,         NaN,     271.170,       0.283, ... 
#max values  :         NaN,         NaN,         NaN,         NaN,     277.090,       0.622, ...
```

What has changed is that the data are now in a file, rather then in memory. And you still have the layer (variable) names.

To write the layers as variables to a NetCDF file you need to create a `SpatRasterDataset`. You can do that like this:

```
x <- as.list(rc)
s <- sds(x)
names(s) <- names(rc)
longnames(s) <- longnames(r)
units(s) <- units(r)
```

Note the use of `longnames(r)` and `units(r)` (not `rc`). This is because `r` has subdatasets (and each has a longname and a unit) while `rc` does not.

Now use `writeCDF`

```
z <- writeCDF(s, "test.nc", overwrite=TRUE)
 
rc2 <- rast("test.nc")
rc2

#class       : SpatRaster 
#dimensions  : 182, 555, 52  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#resolution  : 0.008333333, 0.008333333  (x, y)
#extent      : -83.475, -78.85, 41.38333, 42.9  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
#sources     : test.nc:water_surface_height_above_reference_datum  
              test.nc:water_surface_height_uncertainty  
              test.nc:lake_surface_water_extent  
              ... and 49 more source(s)
#varnames    : water_surface_height_above_reference_datum (water surface height above geoid) 
              water_surface_height_uncertainty (water surface height uncertainty) 
              lake_surface_water_extent (Lake Water Extent) 
              ...
#names       : water~datum, water~ainty, lake_~xtent, lake_~ainty, lake_~ature, lswt_~ainty, ... 
#unit        :           m,           m,         km2,         km2,      Kelvin,      Kelvin, ... 
#time        : 2019-01-01
```

So it looks like we have a NetCDF with the same structure.

Note that the current CRAN version of `terra` drops the `time` variable if there is only one time step. The development version (1.3-11) keeps the time dimension, even of there is only one step.

You can install the development version with
`install.packages('terra', repos='https://rspatial.r-universe.dev')`

Comment: Thank you. This helps to a certain level,  but the time variable is important for me as I will be doing the clipping with several hundred files at different times so I need to retain the time variables.

Comment: You can strore the date in the filename or use the development version (see updated answer)

Comment: Thank you very much! The development version worked! Now I will extend this cropping to all my files!